# Let $A = \{f \in \Bbb I^\Bbb I : |f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|, \text{ for all $x,y \in \Bbb I $}\} \subseteq \Bbb I^\Bbb I$. Is $A$ a compact set?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A = \{f \in \Bbb I^\Bbb I : |f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|, \text{ for all $x,y \in \Bbb I $}\} \subseteq \Bbb I^\Bbb I$. Is $A$ a compact set in $\Bbb I^\Bbb I$?

My guess is that it is. By Tychonoff's theorem the space $\Bbb I^\Bbb I$ is compact so for $A$ to be compact it would need to be a closed set.

$A$ is closed if every sequence $(f_n)_n \in A$ converges pointwise to $f \in A$. Now the set $A$ is consists of functions that are uniformly continuous and since continuous functions on a compact interval are all uniformyl continuous I don't think there can be a case where $f_n \to f$ that isn't uniformly continuous, but I don't know how to verify this claim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are giving $\Bbb I^\Bbb I$  the product topology.

The product topology is not metrizable for a general set $\Bbb I $ so you cannot use sequence to prove closedness. If $(f_i)$ is net in $\Bbb I^\Bbb I $ which converges to $f$ then $(f_i(x)) \to f(x)$ for every $x$, so the inequality in the definition of $A$  is preserved in the limit. Hence, $A$ is closed. (Uniform continuity has nothing to do with this argument). By Tychonoff's Theorem $A is compact.

Comment: I think I have some holes in my understanding, but what difference is there between a net and a sequence?

Comment: @EmilGrönberg In a general topological space you cannot say that a set $A$ is closed if the limit of every convergent sequence form $A$ belongs to $A$. This is true in metric spaces but not in every topological space.